# How to get metrics starting with particular words in Prometheus and what to update in prometheus.yml file

Tags: prometheus

I want to fliter out metrics starting with particular word in prometheus and it should display all the occurrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
{__name__=~"STRING.+"}
```

If you want to search using the REST API execute:

```
curl --globoff --request GET "http://PROMETHEUS-SERVER/api/v1/query?query={__name__=~'prom.%2B'}"
```

Comment: curl 'http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?{__name__=~"prom.+"} ' then I m getting this {"status":"error","errorType":"bad_data","error":"invalid parameter 'query': 1:1: parse error: no expression found in input"}, can u plz correct it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the expression. You didn't mention that you want to use the REST API to get the results. In this case, you need to use this: curl 'localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query={__name__=~"prom.%2B"}'

Comment: $ curl 'localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query={__name__=~"prom.%2B"}' 
{"status":"error","errorType":"bad_data","error":"invalid parameter 'query': 1:9: parse error: unexpected character after '=': '~'"}

Comment: add the "--globoff" parameter to your curl command.

Comment: if want to write the query in prometheus.yml then what needs to do? can u give an example

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, but you could try to add a record rule with "expr: {__name__=~'prom.+'}" and see what happens.